# How to load the react-simple-captcha canvas element inside an MUI Dialog component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, dialog, captcha

I've been trying to implement [react-simple-captcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-captcha) for my React app submission form which is nested inside an MUI Dialog component for a particular page. On other page which the captcha element is not nested inside a Dialog component, it works normal. However, for that particular page where the captcha is nested inside Dialog element, the page went blank and the console returns an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext') at loadCaptchaEnginge`

Here's what the Dialog component code looks like:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { loadCaptchaEnginge, LoadCanvasTemplateNoReload, validateCaptcha } from "react-simple-captcha";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import RefreshIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Refresh";
// some other imports

const FormDialog = ({ open, setOpen }) => {
  //some states & variables declarations
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    //form submit event function
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCaptchaEnginge(6, "#13baba", "#f5f5f5");
  }, []);

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {/* other elements */}
        <LoadCanvasTemplateNoReload />
        <IconButton
          aria-label="Reload Captcha"
          size="small"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => loadCaptchaEnginge(6, "#13baba", "whitesmoke");}}
        >
          <RefreshIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </form>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

The thing is, if I commented out the `useEffect` hook which calls the `loadCaptchaEnginge()` function, the page loads successfully and the `IconButton` calls the `loadCaptchaEnginge()` normally when clicked and the captcha canvas element successfully reloads.

For context, here's what the parent component code which includes the button which calls the FormDialog component looks like:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import FormDialog from "./FormDialog";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
// some other imports

const PageLayout = () => {
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {/* some other elements */}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => setDialogOpen(true)}
      >
        Apply Now
      </Button>
      <FormDialog
        open={dialogOpen}
        setOpen={setDialogOpen}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

After a bit of searching,  I tried using `useRef` hook to create a reference to the FormDialog element and modify the `useEffect` part so the FormDialog become like this:

```
const captchaRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const captchaEl = captchaRef.current;
    if (captchaEl) {
      loadCaptchaEnginge(6, "#13baba", "#f5f5f5");
    }
  }, []);

return (
  <Dialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} ref={captchaRef}>
    {/* rest of the code */}
  <Dialog>
)
```

After implementing this, the page no longer blanks but the captcha canvas is still not rendered initially after the FormDialog appears. Only after the captcha reload button is clicked that the captcha canvas appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem: a canvas element inside a MUI Dialog element.
Solved it by creating a separate Canvas component like this:

```
function Canvas({frequency, amplitude, phase}) {
      const canvasRef = useRef(null)

      useEffect(() => {
          const canvas = canvasRef.current
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
          {/* ... */}

      }, [frequency, amplitude, phase])

      return (
          <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={300} height={150}/>
      )
}
```

... and called that component in the return statement passing the required props:

```
<Dialog>
    <DialogContent>
        <Canvas
            props={sliderOneValue}
            amplitude={sliderTwoValue}
            phase={sliderThreeValue}
        />
    {/* ... */}
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```